# Does being asymptotic imply the use of Big-O notation and vice-versa?

Tags: asymptotics

Suppose that $f(x)\sim g(x)$, then does $f(x)=O(g(x))$? Conversely, suppose that $f(x)=O(g(x))$, then does $f(x)\sim g(x)$?

Comment: The first statement is true, the second is not.

Comment: Strictly speaking, by $=O$ you mean $\in O$. You may be interested to notice $f\sim g\iff f-g\in o(g)$.

Answer (score 1):

It is useful to recognize that

- "$f(x)=O(g(x))$" is equivalent to "there exists a constant $C$ such that $\left|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right| \le C$ for sufficiently large $x$."
- $f(x) \sim g(x)$ is defined as $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \to 1$.

From here, we immediately see that $f(x) \sim g(x)$ implies $f(x)=O(g(x))$ (take $C=2$, for instance).

However, the converse does not hold. For example, $f(x)=2x$ and $g(x)=x$ satisfy $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \le 2$ but $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \not\to 1$.